# Como puedo obtener el id que inserta en la base de datos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

se puede obtener el id que inserta en la base de datos?

```
    Reserva::insert([
  'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
  'dia_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
]);
```

para luego poder trabajar con el id por ejemplo

```
$reserva->id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El metodo *insert* devueve un valor booleano, en su lugar puedes usar el metodo *create* que te devuelve todos los datos del registro creado

```
$reserva = Reserva::create([
                    'user_id' => Session::get('user_id'),
                    'dia_id' => Session::get('variableName')
]);


$reserva->id;
```